# BlueMix : How to deploy services on PaaS

Tags: cloud, apache-kafka, ibm-cloud, paas, message-hub

I would like to run the following services on a Bluemix cloud

1. Apache Kafka
2. Apache Storm
3. Elasticsearch

a few questions

1. Is this even possible? For example, what does it mean to run Kafka on cloud?
2. Will the data be stored on the cloud as well?
3. Will all of these services require Liberty WAS?
4. Are there any already available services for these? Or for doing these tasks?

I know its a broad question but i am really hoping for some insights in order to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of existing services in the catalogue that provide these applications.

- [IBM Message Hub](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/message-hub/) is an Apache Kafka service.
- [Elastic Search](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/elasticsearch-by-compose/) is provided by the [Compose](https://www.compose.io/).

Apache Storm is not available as a hosted service at the moment.

These services are separate from the application runtime, e.g. Liberty.

Comment: Yep! That's there too.